# Crossfilter map function into MongoDB queries

Tags: mongodb, server, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a project that runs with crossfilter server-side. The problem is that we have to instanciate the json data into crossfilter in order to filter. If we have more project's in the server this will cause a huge amount of RAM usage.

My aim is to "convert" the API of crossfilter into a MongoDB queries.

Can someone point me in the right direction or attempted this before? Thanks